# AngularJS API GET request

Tags: angularjs, api, get, authorization, imgur

I believe I am correctly including my access token, so I'm a bit confused about why I still get a `Permission Denied` response from https://www.api.imgur.com/3/album. Please see my code below:

```
$http.get('https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=token').then(function(json){
  console.log(json);
  $scope.token = json.config.headers.Authorization;
  $http({
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/album/rX8ws',
    Authorization: $scope.token,
    type: 'GET'
  })
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Best regards,

Peter

## =============Update====================

Adjusted my request to encapsulate Authorization key in `headers` like this:

```
$http.get('https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=117ab4fd3e5fb89&response_type=token').then(function(json){
  console.log(json);
  $scope.token = json.config.headers.Authorization;
  $http({
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/album/rX8ws',
    headers: {
       Authorization: $scope.token, //added token in headers
    },
    type: 'GET'
  })
})
```

and still getting a `403 Permission Denied`

## =============Update-2==================

Tried changing `type: 'GET'` to `method: 'GET'` to no avail. Still returns a `403 (Permission Denied)`

Answer (score 1):

It should be passed through the `headers` option of `$http` request & also change `type: 'GET'` to  `method: 'GET'`

**Code**

```
$http.get('https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=pin').then(function(json){
  console.log(json);
  $scope.pin = json.config.headers.Authorization;
  $http({
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/album/rX8ws',
    headers: {
       Authorization: $scope.pin, //added token in headers
    }
    method: 'GET' //changed type to method
  })
})
```

Comment: Just tried that a few times and still got `403 Permission Denied`

Comment: @PeterWard from `type: 'GET'` to  `method: 'GET'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried call this same request in some rest client or something like this?

I like to use this one [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Comment: I don't use technology that may not be installed by my users. This kind of request is nothing that a MEAN application cannot handle.

Comment: Advanced REST client is only for tests. I just asked if you had tested this same request in other rest client than yours. Whatever... In imgur documentation I found some examples about this kind of request. It seems to work with POST method and this header Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token instead yours.